# Overwrite Library Word file with PDF and keep SharePoint Document ID

Tags: 2013, document-library, metadata

We are moving from Documentum to SharePoint 2013, and are trying to test whether we can check out a Word file from a SharePoint library and then when I check in the file, overwrite it with a PDF version of the file I checked out, essentially changing the file format, but retaining the unique document ID number (the link which may be in other documents and sites).

Is this possible?  This type of scenario is possible in Documentum, but looks like it is NOT in SharePoint because once the file name / type / extension changes, that's a new document in the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you should be able to rename your old document to the new document name and format.

When you do this, the id should remain the same.

Then you can overwrite your pdf which will be added as a new version.

Needless to say, if you try to open previous versions adobe will probably open and complain the file format is invalid.

I have tested this in explorer view with SP2010. Don't think the behaviour has changed since, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Hi Tiago!  This worked in our 2013 environment except if you click on the Document ID column, it's saying "No documents with the ID ...found in this site collection"

Comment: at what stage of the process does it fail? maybe you can run the document id service timer job and see if it helps

Comment: Hi Tiago...thanks for the reply!  The "No documents with the ID" error message looks like it was on a bad library.  We've tried on a good library, and get page not found when you click the Document ID hyperlink column.  Our crawl happens hourly from what I can tell, so we're waiting for that to run and see what happens...will keep you posted...thank you!

Comment: great...just waited for crawler...and works!  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: glad to hear that. feel free to mark my answer as the solution if you believe it is so